# get same value for keys into another dictionary from List of Dictionary

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Here is my list of dictionary.

```
d = [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]
```

How can I get output like below:

```
d_one = [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
         {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}]

d_two = [{'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]
```

Getting distinct data from list of dictionary from two keys zone and cycle. For same zone and cycle pair create one list of dictionary and it goes till end.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I am using django framework. So by using its ORM it gives me list of dictionary which I have given in d variable.  So I will get variable data and list items too. Sometimes I may have 1 item in it or 50 too. So I want create new dictionary of same values of zone and cycle key. If total pair is 3 or 5 then dictionary should get created respectiely

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all: where's your attempt to implement this functionality? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: My dear friend, of course I tried something which was not working. I tried something as doing looping and then comparing but the problem was that I was not on the right way as I had no clue what to do with this. That's why I called for help. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: So *where is it*? Give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dict using pairs `(dct['zone'], dct['cycle'])` as keys:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> 
>>> for dct in d:
...     result.setdefault((dct['zone'], dct['cycle']), []).append(dct)
... 
>>> result
{('PIMPRI', '15'): [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}, {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}], ('PIMPRI', '30'): [{'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]}
```

Comment: I modified code a bit and done with this approach. Thanks all and sorry for late comment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter) your data :

```
d_one = filter(lambda d:d['cycle']=='15',d)
> [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}, 
>  {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}]
```

and

```
d_two = filter(lambda d:d['cycle']=='30',d)
> [{'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use **collections**. And have your variable(`'cycle'`) as key in a dict.

Ex:

```
import collections 
res = collections.defaultdict(list)
d = [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]

for i in d:
    res[i["cycle"]].append(i)
print(res['15'])
print("-----")
print(res['30'])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}, {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'}]
-----
[{'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `groupby`,

```
from itertools import groupby 
from operator import itemgetter
grouper = itemgetter("cycle", "zone")
dict_one,dict_two = (list(g) for _,g in groupby(d,key=grouper))
```

The code will return a tuple now we have only 2 elements. So the value assignment will work here. If you have more values you can assign these values to a `dict` or store as iterable.

**Output**

```
In [9]: dict_one
Out[9]: 
[{'count': '100', 'cycle': '15', 'zone': 'PIMPRI'},
 {'count': '50', 'cycle': '15', 'zone': 'PIMPRI'}]

In [10]: dict_two
Out[10]: [{'count': '150', 'cycle': '30', 'zone': 'PIMPRI'}]
```

Comment: what if more values ? and not only cycle, zone also he specified.

Comment: @VikasDamodar OP described two values, So a specific solution written here. Anyway if you have more values. We can get as iterable.

Comment: what about zone ?

Comment: see OP's comment he may have more values .

Comment: Updated the answer.  And he can add more values in `grouper`.

Comment: here you have only dict_one and dict_two, what if he has more than two group of data ?

Comment: Please read OP's comment in question, he is said he may have more values.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Why to use separate dictionaries for all those values. Couldn't you make it to a single dictionary. For your example,

```
d = [{'count': '100', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '50', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '15'},
     {'count': '150', 'zone': 'PIMPRI', 'cycle': '30'}]
```

this is what we could get,

```
res = {}
for ele in d:
    res.setdefault((ele['cycle'],ele['zone']), [])
    res[(ele['cycle'], ele['zone'])].append(ele['count'])
```